# How do I use Token() method in Sprache parser

Tags: sprache

I'm using 'Token()' method to discard leading and trailing whitespaces but it won't, this test fails with message
`Expected string to be "token", but it has unexpected whitespace at the end.`

I tried to call method `Token()` before method `Text()` but it won't help too.
`Parse.AnyChar.Many().Token().Text()`

How do I use method `Token()` in a right way?

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
  Parser<string> parser = Parse.AnyChar.Many().Text().Token();
  var actual = parser.Parse(" token ");

  actual.Should().Be("token"); // without leading and trailing whitespaces
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Parse.AnyChar` consumes the trailing whitespace before the `Token` modifier comes into play.

To fix the parser, exclude the whitespace like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var parser = Parse.AnyChar.Except(Parse.WhiteSpace).Many().Text().Token();
    var actual = parser.Parse(" token ");

    actual.Should().Be("token"); // without leading and trailing whitespaces
}
```